# Grails Quartz scheduler stopped running

Tags: java, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job running in a production grails app that was running fine for several days.  Every day at 9 AM (2 PM at server local time) I have it perform a task then email me with the results (using the mail plugin).  For several weeks this worked fine, but for the past few days I have not received the email (Checked the outgoing SMTP, looks like the email isn't even getting generated).  I have determined that the job is not running.  Any idea why a quartz job would just stop?

Here's my job:

```
class RenewJob {

    def communicationService
    def permissionsService
    def emailService

    // Daily at 2
    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'dailyJob', cronExpression: "0 0 14 ? * MON-SUN"
    }

    //method calls obviously obfuscated
    def execute() {
        def renewals = communicationService.doSomethingWithCommunication()
        def expires = permissionsService.doSomethingWithPermissions()
        emailService.sendDailyJobSummaryEmail(renewals, expires);
    }
}
```

And my Quartz Configuration:

```
quartz {
  autoStartup = true
}
environments {
    test {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
    development {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it worked fine for several weeks and then stopped. The cron format clearly works then, so have you looked at the log files? Be especially on the lookout for [stuck threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618265/quartz-scheduler-suddenly-stop-running-and-no-exception-error) which would have the effect of running your job 10 (or 20, or whatever times) and then not running any more due to the thread pool being used up.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll check through my logs and see if I uncover anything.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618265/quartz-scheduler-suddenly-stop-running-and-no-exception-error

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022379/grails-quartz2-job-stops-randomly